# How does the system handle huge amounts of shared memory?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, shared-memory

I have a system with about 64G of RAM and about 24G of swap space. I accidentally allocated a huge amount of shared memory in my program, and to my surprise it worked. Here's the file in `/dev/shm`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  191G Aug  7 10:06 myShm
```

How is the system managing 191GB of shared memory when my RAM and swap add up to only a fraction of that?

Comment: It's probably existing in virtual memory. As long as there is completely unused memory,the computer is smart enough to pretend it exists but not try to do anything with it. maybe you're using a gig of the shared memory, so that gig is in memory, the rest of it is virtually defined but not physically existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your system is assigning virtual memory not physical memory. when you touch/use specific memory it will be allocated. ussually All OS are intelligent enough to "over commit" the memory.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have some kind of link or additional reading about the details of how this works for linux?

Comment: my most favorite book is unix kernel development It has very good narration about user space and kernel space memory functions and borderlines